# Col Gutter Shadow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When using Bootstrap 4, I divided the row on 4 col-3 and each col-3 on 2 rows that have col-12. The default gutter is exactly what I need, however when I want to shadow the divs, it shadows like there is no gutter and I need a solution.

[image: Link to the image]

In the image above, you can see the shadow ignoring the gutter and the red line I draw around the div is where I would like the shadow to appear.

```
<div class="row mt-4">

        <div class="col-sm-3 shadow-sm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="bluebg text-white p-2">
                        <span class="text-uppercase">Sign In</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <i class="text-dark fas fa-user fa-7x my-3"></i>
                        <p class="redtext text-uppercase font-weight-bold my-1">Sign In</p>
                        <p>Login with your roblox username.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 shadow-sm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="bluebg text-white p-2">
                        <span class="text-uppercase">Sign In</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <i class="text-dark fas fa-user fa-7x my-3"></i>
                        <p class="redtext text-uppercase font-weight-bold my-1">Sign In</p>
                        <p>Login with your roblox username.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 shadow-sm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="bluebg text-white p-2">
                        <span class="text-uppercase">Sign In</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <i class="text-dark fas fa-user fa-7x my-3"></i>
                        <p class="redtext text-uppercase font-weight-bold my-1">Sign In</p>
                        <p>Login with your roblox username.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 shadow-sm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="bluebg text-white p-2">
                        <span class="text-uppercase">Sign In</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <i class="text-dark fas fa-user fa-7x my-3"></i>
                        <p class="redtext text-uppercase font-weight-bold my-1">Sign In</p>
                        <p>Login with your roblox username.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

This is the code I have problems with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things which I did:

- started with a `container-fluid` div, because starting with `row` class will give you a scroll at the bottom
- the `shadow-sm` class gets its own div inside the `col-sm-3`
- you don't need 2 `row` Divs in inside the `col-sm-3`

Working **snippet** below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class="row mt-4">

    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
      <div class='shadow-sm'>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="bluebg text-white p-2">
              <span class="text-uppercase">Sign In</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="text-center">
              <i class="text-dark fas fa-user fa-7x my-3"></i>
              <p class="redtext text-uppercase font-weight-bold my-1">Sign In</p>
              <p>Login with your roblox username.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
      <div class='shadow-sm'>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="bluebg text-white p-2">
              <span class="text-uppercase">Sign In</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="text-center">
              <i class="text-dark fas fa-user fa-7x my-3"></i>
              <p class="redtext text-uppercase font-weight-bold my-1">Sign In</p>
              <p>Login with your roblox username.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="shadow-sm">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="bluebg text-white p-2">
              <span class="text-uppercase">Sign In</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="text-center">
              <i class="text-dark fas fa-user fa-7x my-3"></i>
              <p class="redtext text-uppercase font-weight-bold my-1">Sign In</p>
              <p>Login with your roblox username.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
      <div class="shadow-sm">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="bluebg text-white p-2">
              <span class="text-uppercase">Sign In</span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="text-center">
              <i class="text-dark fas fa-user fa-7x my-3"></i>
              <p class="redtext text-uppercase font-weight-bold my-1">Sign In</p>
              <p>Login with your roblox username.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I just started with Bootstrap and I couldn't find any relative questions to this so this helped me a lot!